# Centering a subcaption

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

I have three figures that I want to place next to each other. That is fine. In addition, however, each `subfigure` has a caption on its own and the crucial thing with these is that I have to have two lines for each of them generated by a linebreak. I managed that using `\newline`, but now the subcaption always starts on the left edge of the subfigures and is not centered any more (which does not look nice).

What can I do to resolve my problem?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphix,subcaption}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
      \begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1}
          \caption{\centering Nice image1.\newline Another line.}
          \label{fig:NiceImage1}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1}
          \caption{\centering Nice image 2.\newline Another line.}
          \label{fig:NiceImage2}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1}
          \caption{\centering Nice image 2.\newline Another line.}
          \label{fig:NiceImage3}
      \end{subfigure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) have you tried adding `\centering` inside each `subfigure`?

Comment: @cmhughes since the subfigures occupy all the available width of their corresponding `subfigure` environment, `\centering` won't have any effect. Besides, `\centering` doesn't affect the caption which is the problem here.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use `justification=centering` for `\captionsetup`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
    \centering
      \begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1}
          \caption{Nice image1. \\ Another line.}
          \label{fig:NiceImage1}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1}
          \caption{Nice image 2. \\ Another line.}
          \label{fig:NiceImage2}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1}
          \caption{Nice image 3. \\ Another line.}
          \label{fig:NiceImage3}
      \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: several years later, this answer is still relevant. thank you!