# How to align standalone TikZ pictures horizontally?

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

Today I discovered the existence of this wonderful package called "standalone". I really love it because I have a lot of pictures in Tikz code and some of them have a very long code and it's very difficult to handle and annoying when I'm trying to concentrate on the text rather than on pictures. So here is my problem, I have some small pictures that I want to align in the same row (sometimes 2, 3 or 4 of them in the same row). Let's suppose that I have these stand alone pictures:

Picture1.tex:

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
    \draw [domain=0.08:3.92] plot(\x,{(--1.04--0.32*\x)/1.96});
    \draw (3.6,0.98) node[anchor=north west] {$l_a$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Picture2.tex:

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
    \draw [domain=0.08:3.92] plot(\x,{(--1.04--0.32*\x)/1.96});
    \draw (3.6,0.98) node[anchor=north west] {$l_b$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Within the body of my main Tex file:

```
%... 
impute(Picture1.tex)
impute(Picture2.tex)
%
```

I want my pictures look like this: 
[image]

Also I wanted that my pictures have a general description below them. My first try was by using "figure" environment  (\begin{figure}.../end{figure}) but the pictures are put in a different position rather than just after a given line of text, I don't want that the picture appears anywhere else like at the top of the page or something. Thank you so much for your help and so sorry if my question is so naive but I'm just starting to learn these things.

Comment: you could put them in `minipages` or `subfigures` from the `subcaption` package

Comment: @cmhughes Thank yo so much. I almost have it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111556/centering-a-subcaption

Comment: @cmhughes How can I fix the figures so they appear just after the given line of text and not at the top of the page?

Comment: sounds like you don't want them to float-[Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275)

Comment: You can put images into a tabular (my favorite).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said by Chris in comments, you can use `minipage`s. To have caption and not to allow floating, you can avoid `figure` environment and use `\captionof` macro from either `caption` or `capt-of` packages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off,hang]{caption}     %% provides \captionof command. capt-of package does this too.
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{picture1.tex}
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
    \draw [domain=0.08:3.92] plot(\x,{(--1.04--0.32*\x)/1.96});
    \draw (3.6,0.98) node[anchor=north west] {$l_a$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{picture2.tex}
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
    \draw [domain=0.08:3.92] plot(\x,{(--1.04--0.32*\x)/1.96});
    \draw (3.6,0.98) node[anchor=north west] {$l_b$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
\includestandalone{picture1}
\captionof{figure}{Some description of figure comes here}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
\includestandalone{picture2}
\captionof{figure}{Some description of }
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can use `subfigure` from `subcaption` package. In this case you will need `float` package that provides `[H]` position specifier.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off,hang]{caption}     %% for formatting captions
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}   %% for controlling float position, provides [H] postion specifier.
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{picture1.tex}
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
    \draw [domain=0.08:3.92] plot(\x,{(--1.04--0.32*\x)/1.96});
    \draw (3.6,0.98) node[anchor=north west] {$l_a$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{picture2.tex}
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
    \draw [domain=0.08:3.92] plot(\x,{(--1.04--0.32*\x)/1.96});
    \draw (3.6,0.98) node[anchor=north west] {$l_b$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
Some text comes here
\begin{figure}[H]
   \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\textwidth}
        \includestandalone{picture1}
        \caption{Some description of figure comes here}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
   \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\textwidth}
        \includestandalone{picture2}
        \caption{Some description of figure}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same can be achieved with `subfig` package also. This is left as an exercise.