# Centering Subcaptions including a linebreak

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

I found an asnwered question concerning this topic already here:
[Centering a subcaption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111556/centering-a-subcaption)
Copying `\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}` doesn't help me thought for I am using different packages.

I would like my Captions and Subcaptions to be justified as the text below. Just under my pictures. Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, justification=justified]{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% Remove demo option in real document

\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}
%   \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
    \centering  
    \subfloat[Subcaption one \newline including a linebreak ]   {
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{image1}
    }
    \hspace{1cm}
    \subfloat[Subcaption two \newline including a linebreak]
    {
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{image2}
    }   
    \caption{Figure caption \newline with additional text right here}
\end{figure}

\begin{center}
This is correctly justified Text \\ including a longer linebreak than blabla.
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The command `\subfloat` has two optional arguments, the first being the LoF entry.

So, substituting lines like

```
\subfloat[Subcaption one \newline including a linebreak]
```

with

```
\subfloat[Subcaption one including a linebreak][Subcaption one \\ including a linebreak]
```

does the job.

MWE (I've also removed some spurious spaces with `%`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, justification=justified]{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% Remove demo option in real document

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
   \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
    \centering
    \subfloat[Subcaption one including a linebreak][Subcaption one \\ including a linebreak]
    {%
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{image1}%
    }%
    \hspace{1cm}%
    \subfloat[Subcaption two including a linebreak][Subcaption two \\ including a linebreak]
    {%
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{image2}%
    }
    \caption{Figure caption \\ with additional text right here}
\end{figure}

\begin{center}
This is correctly justified Text \\ including a longer linebreak than blabla.
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Do you have to do anything special to allow `\\` in the subcaptions? I get errors whereas `\newline` works fine. This is in a rather complex document so I just wondered if there's anything I can check for easily as I've never used `subfig` before. (If not, I might try to create an MWE but I'll probably just use `\newline` even if I really ought not.)